# Alter CSV file in Windows

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

Is it possible to read the contents of .csv and add another column data for every record ?.

Example : The input CSV will have the following contents

```
Row 1 : C1 C2 C3 C4 <C5>
...........
```

Is it feasible to set the C5 data with a fixed value using Windows scripting ?

Then the .csv file should be saved also with the added column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description i assume you have a csv file to which you want to add an extra column and for every row add a value to thos column.

Assuming the in-file is input.csv and the output is output.csv this line in Powershell would do the trick. It takes a file input.csv in your current directory and outputs a file output.csv with an extra column HEADER and constant value VALUE.

I have broken it to several lines for ease of reading...

```
 $n=0;
 Get-Content .\input.csv |
 ForEach-Object{ If($n -eq 0){ $n=1; $_ + ",HEADER" } Else { $_+",VALUE"} } |
 Out-File output.csv
```

**UPDATE**: To make a batfile of the command, you should prefix it with "powershell -Command".

In summary: you want the bat-file to contain the following line:

`powershell.exe -Command "$n=0; Get-Content .\input.csv | ForEach-Object{ If($n -eq 0){ $n=1; $_ + ',HEADER' } Else { $_+',VALUE'} } | Out-File output.csv"`

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this powershell. Can i put the above statements in a batch file and call it as such ?

Answer (score 1):

```
powershell $cn=gc cn.csv;$cl=gc c1.csv;$i=0;$cn^|%{$cn[$i]+','+$cl[$i];++$i}>result.csv
```